# How to get a particular session path in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save a particular session as a path. So if I delete it from MySQL database, the session would be deleted too...

Is this possible? 
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have a misconception. Passing a parameter to `session_save_path` changes the path. You should read the manual for `session_save_path` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php which says `If specified, the path to which data is saved will be changed. session_save_path() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose.`

Comment: Ok thank, but that's not the solution in my case...

Comment: AFAIK there are no seperate folders for different session variables. All session related files will go to `session_save_path`.

Comment: Ok, but what I want is to keep session path in MySQL database when user logs in... I will update my question to make it clear...

Comment: To have complete control of user session data then you can store all the session data in a database. an example of code to do this: [Codeproject.com/Articles/Session-Storage-in-a-MySQL-Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798978/Session-Storage-in-a-MySQL-Database)

Comment: Hi thank you, I 've read through the article but I don't see how can you insert the data into the database. I'm new to this. It would be really helpful if you could post an answer :)

Comment: The article assumes using `PDO` as your prefered database framework. Quote: `Lets say you have some Database class that is extension of PDO.`

Comment: Hi guys, I have looked at the article and posted the code as an answer. Do you think theres a better/ shorter way to do this? Because all I want is to get the session address... 

IF not please help me with the code I've posted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is what I did... Please check if this code is correct and **will be able to insert $_SESSION['email'] to db as a path...**

```
   <?php session_set_save_handler(
        "openSession",
        "closeSession",
        "readSession",
        "writeSession",
        "destroySession",
        "gcSession"
    ); 

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "**password**", "**table**");

class Session {
    /** @var Database */
    private $mysqli;

}


function __construct()
{
    // instance of new Database object
    $this->mysqli = CDatabase::init(); //check this

    // set handler to overide SESSION
    @session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, "openSession"),
        array($this, "closeSession"),
        array($this, "readSession"),
        array($this, "writeSession"),
        array($this, "destroySession"),
        array($this, "gcSession")
    );

    // start the session
    session_start();
}


public function openSession(
    // if database connection exists
    if($this->_db){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public function closeSession()
{
    // if database connection is closed
    if($this->mysqli->close()){
        @session_write_close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;    
}

 $email = $_SESSION['email'];
public function readSession($email)
{
    $result = $this->mysqli->select(
        "SELECT session_data FROM sessions WHERE session_id = :session_id",
        array(":session_id"=>$email)
    );
    return isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : "";
}


public function writeSession($email)
{        
    $result = $this->mysqli->insert(
        "INSERT INTO table VALUES (session_id = :session_id)",
        array(":session_id"=>$email)
    );
    if(isset($result[0])){
        $result = $this->mysqli->update(
            "sessions",
            array(
                "expires_at"=>time()+$this->getTimeout(),
                "session_data"=>$data
            ),
            "session_id = :session_id",
            array(":session_id"=>$id)
        );
    }else{
        $result = $this->_db->insert(
            "sessions",
            array(
                "session_id"=>$email,
                "expires_at"=>time()+$this->getTimeout()

            )
        );
    }

    return true;
}

public function destroySession($email)
{
    return $this->_db->delete(
        "sessions", "session_id = :session_id", array(":session_id"=>$email)
    );        
}


public function gcSession($maxLifetime)
{
    return $this->_db->delete(
        "sessions", "expires_at < :expires_at", array(":expires_at"=>time())
    );
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Those functions kind of need to be part of the class.... Also i think you are confused about that a path is in terms of the session. The session save path is a location on the filesystem when you use file based session handling. You are attempting to implement database session handling so there will be no save path... just a record in the database tied to a session id. That single database record will contain **all** the data for a particular client's session.

Comment: Asking, answering yourself, and accepting your own answer - leads to poor outcomes. In this case you will be creating a new database record for the session on every requests, defeating the purpose of a session. Several issues; SQL should be `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to prevent new session records for each request, and a session exists for the class constructor, also should be a singleton class just n case poor programming results in creating more than one of these for a single request. then there is defining an identifier that can be reproducible a.k.a sticky session token